# Fortnite Install issues

Tags: technical-issues, fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world, epic-games-launcher

I am trying to download an update for Fortnite.  However downloading the patch seems near impossible. It will burst up to 100KB/s at most and then just drop. Making a 4 gb download take ages. I then pause it and download a game on steam. Where I get 1MB/s, seems strange to me as pretty much the only internet process running in the house.

I have tried the [following](http://fortnitehelp.epicgames.com/customer/portal/articles/2293545-the-download-gets-stuck-at-a-certain-percentage-and-will-not-progress-when-attempting-to-download-content-from-the-epic-games-launcher?b_id=9729) (adding lines to config file)

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

> [Portal.BuildPatch]
>
> ChunkDownloads=3

[image]

Comment: Did you try to switch your network connection? From Wi-fi to LAN, or maybe try to share your mobile data... 
League of Legends often drops the download speed while updating to the latest patch. I suggest you to close the Launcher, and to restart the update.

Comment: Hi Kevin, It seems like your disc (write) is not able to keep up with your download. Are you using a hard drive or an SSD? Is there enough free space? How old is your drive?

Answer (score 0):

I used the code plus a few others which I have put down below.

I did this because I’m using Ethernet and was finding speeds was 100/300KB/s which was very slow, after I did add the codes into the config file it is now running 6.5to7.3MB/s which in my case is a massive increase.

Codes below have helped and are not fake well not for me anyways.

[Portal.BuildPatch] 
ChunkDownloads=3
ChunkRetries=20 
RetryTime=0.5

Paste these into the Engine.ini file inside the config folder for epic games launcher

Ctrl + R (%appdata%) > Local > EpicGamesLauncher > Saved > Config > Windows > Engine.ini

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me on my computer. I deleted some old files off my computer I did not need anymore. I then rebooted my computer and tried again it seemed to work well after that. Hope this fixes the problem.

Comment: "deleting some things off my computer" is incredibly vague. Did you mean you freed up space by deleting old files you didn't need, or something different? If you could add some information, it would help make this a much better answer.

Comment: @Dragonrage yes I meant deleting old files

Answer (score -2):

In the epic games launcher the speed of you internet doesn't matter the stability does meaning how long it can proceed with the internet connection speed. So don't try all those codes most are fake and do nothing you can only wait for it to finish